# Why the array cannot assign value for wdata?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I write a test that when I write data, another array will keep data to compare to red data correct or not. However, the array only print x to me.

```
reg [31:0]  wdata;
reg [31:0]  array_wdata [0:15];
wire [31:0] rdata;

task check_read; 
      begin
      integer i;

     for (i=0; i<16; i+=1)
       begin
          @(negedge clk) begin
         wr_en_i = 1;
         wdata = wdata + 1;
         array_wdata[i] = wdata;
          end
       end

     for (i=0; i<16; i+=1)
       begin
          $display( "\tArray data[i]=%0d", array_wdata[i]);
       end

end
endtask
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `wdata` as a `reg`, which means it will have an initial value of X.  Since you are only seeing X printed out, it likely means that you did not assign an initial value before the 1st call to the `check_read` task.  Also, when you add 1 to X, the result is still X.

To get rid of these X's, you need to set `wdata` before you call the task.  For example:

```
module tb;

reg wr_en_i;
reg [31:0]  wdata;
reg [31:0]  array_wdata [0:15];
wire [31:0] rdata;
bit clk;
always #5 clk++;

task check_read; 
      begin
      integer i;

     for (i=0; i<16; i+=1)
       begin
          @(negedge clk) begin
         wr_en_i = 1;
         wdata = wdata + 1;
         array_wdata[i] = wdata;
          end
       end

     for (i=0; i<16; i+=1)
       begin
          $display( "\tArray data[i]=%0d", array_wdata[i]);
       end

end
endtask

initial begin
    wdata = 'h5555;
    check_read();
    #500 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Outputs:

```
Array data[i]=21846
Array data[i]=21847
Array data[i]=21848
Array data[i]=21849
Array data[i]=21850
Array data[i]=21851
Array data[i]=21852
Array data[i]=21853
Array data[i]=21854
Array data[i]=21855
Array data[i]=21856
Array data[i]=21857
Array data[i]=21858
Array data[i]=21859
Array data[i]=21860
Array data[i]=21861
```